# Асимптотика добавления значения по ключу в hash-таблицу

Tags: java-hashmap

Почему не O(n), ведь для добавления, сначала проверяются все ключи в hash-таблице, и если ключа нет, то он и добавляется

Comment: Для добавления значения проверять все ключи не нужно. В том-то вся и хитрость хеш-таблиц.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем так, проверять нам все ключи смысла нет, т.к в случае если мы кладем пару, у которой ключ уже лежит в хешмапе, то предыдущее значение просто перезапишется.

Вот выдержка из JavaDoc метода put класса HashMap:

> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If
> the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is
> replaced.
>
> Returns: the previous value associated with key, or null if there was
> no mapping for key. (A null return can also indicate that the map
> previously associated null with key.)